# Android home button, Timer issue

Tags: java, android, hide, android-homebutton

My App seems to restart everytime the App is Run after the Home button is pressed. The App has a `Timer` which needs to continue once the Home button is pressed. I override the Back button to minimize the app if the `Timer` is on, is there a way to do this with the Home button?

My `onResume()` is this at the moment:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: use onPause rather than onBackPressed.

Comment: Check onkeydown event in android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The App has a Timer() which needs to continue once the Home button is pressed.

I suggest a different approach: log the time the Timer started and simply recreate the Timer in `onResume()`.  This way you don't have to worry about the app being killed, running the Timer in a service, etc.  If you want a task to be run while the app is paused, setup a AlarmManager event in `onPause()`.

---

> I override the Back button to Minimise the app if the Timer() is on, is there a way to do this with the Home button?

To address this specifically, you can use [`onUserLeaveHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) or the generalized `onPause()`.